# Elastic Search - How to update mapping field from keyword to text

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, mapping, full-text-search

```
{
   "properties":{
      "device":{
         "type":"object",
         "properties":{
            "id":{
               "type":"keyword"
            },
            "value":{
               "type":"keyword"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I wanted to update mapping value as text, when I'm trying to update using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html throws an error.
"mapper [device.value] of different type, current_type [keyword], merged_type [text]"

```
{
   "properties":{
      "device":{
         "type":"object",
         "properties":{
            "id":{
               "type":"keyword"
            },
            "value":{
               "type":"text"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Someone help me update index from keyword to text?

Comment: its been sometime, please comment if you are able to fix issue

Comment: I decided to drop existing index and create new one. It's ok to create new index and re-indexing all the existing data. Thanks @Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing field type is a breaking change, you need to

1. Create a new index with new required mapping.
2. use [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) to move data from old to new index(optional if you are OK with data loss)